# Windows wont boot after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I know there are a lot of questions about this around here but I have yet to find a solution for my problem.

I have windows 10 on my SSD in my /C: disk, and since today Ubuntu 16.04 on my HDD, which is the /E: disk.

After installing ubuntu I could no longer boot back into my windows. 
While creating the partitions I noticed something called Windows boot loader disappeared (I think). Im guessing this has to do with the problem

I have tried using boot-repair to fix the issues, which managed to show me the GRUB boot menu, but still windows is not listed there. I also got an error while doing the repair, this is the pastebin:

http://paste2.org/XNVyhtEF

I also tried things like

```
$ ntfsfix /dev/[partition]
```

but this gives me the following:

```
Mounting volume... Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted
```

Trying to go into the disk through the file explorer gives the following error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/maxoe/Harddisk: Command-line `mount       -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/maxoe/Harddisk"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

At this point Im completely clueless and Im starting to think I might have lost everything on my windows disk.

Any help would be welcome!

**UPDATE**

This is the output after running "sudo update-grub":

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
done
```

Comment: Are you able to boot into Ubuntu?  If so, boot to Ubuntu, then run `sudo update-grub`.  Add the output to your question.  After running the command rebooting should show you Windows in the boot menu.  It may show you two versions.  Try one then try the other.  The results of what you show in your Queston for the output of the command will help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Yes I am. I tried running that command, but still only "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu advanced options" show up in the boot menu... I added the output to my post!

Comment: Which version of Windows did you have operating before?  Also was the mode EFI or Legacy?

Comment: Im not sure what exact version, but it was windows 10 and I think it was fully updated. I believe its in legacy mode.

Comment: The answer may be obvious, but what do you get when run these commands:  (1) `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` and `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt`?  Sorry for the many questions.  Most of the answers are in the boot repair you linked.  But I'm still checking and verifying what might be obvious.

Comment: No problem at all! Im just glad youre trying to help. The first command results in: "mount: can't find /dev/sdb1 in /etc/fstab" and the second command gives: "The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Operation not permitted, The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52965/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-max-taylor).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 0):

When dual booting Windows, if you hibernate windows instead of fully shutting it down or fast startup is on (which may be the default for Windows 10) you won't be able to mount the partition in Ubuntu. Based on the output of `ntfsfix` this may be what has happened here and what is stopping Ubuntu from being able to add it to the grub.

This accepted answer to this question ([Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)) mentions a few ways of mounting a hibernated windows partition from Ubuntu. Doing this may let `update-grub` add windows to your startup menu.

Comment: I tried his solution. it did help me get read-access to my windows files, which is great because I can atleast make backups if all goes wrong. But still I cant boot into windows.

Comment: You need to run update-grub again, obviously. @MaxTaylor

Comment: I did that, obviously. If you had taken the time to read the comments on my post you would be more up to date ^^